# Issue with kable() output after loading TBDBr package in Quarto document

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, quarto

I'm having an issue with table output once I load the `TBDBr` package (https://github.com/TalkBank/TBDBr) in my Quarto document.

Here's a reproducible example of my `.qmd` document with the rendered tables.

````
---
title: "Test document"
format: html
---

Load in the basic packages. 

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| message: false
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
```

Create a table using `kable()`. 

```{r}
#| label: tbl-test-1
#| tbl-cap: 'Good table.'

iris |> 
  slice_head(n = 10) |> 
  kable()
```
````

[image: Good table]

````
Load the `TBDBr` package and then run the same code as above to generate a table using `kable()`. 

```{r}
#| label: tbl-test-2
#| tab-cap: 'Bad table.'

library(TBDBr)

iris |> 
  slice_head(n = 10) |> 
  kable()
```
````

[image: Bad table]

---

I suspect that it may have something to do with `kableExtra` being loaded as a dependency with the `TBDBr` package.

Here's my session info if it is of any help.

```
─ Session info 

 version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
 os       macOS Monterey 12.6
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/New_York
 date     2022-10-18
 rstudio  2022.07.1+554 Spotted Wakerobin (desktop)
 pandoc   2.19.2 @ /usr/local/bin/ (via markdown)


─ Packages 

 package   * version date (UTC) lib source
 dplyr     * 1.0.10  2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 forcats   * 0.5.2   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 ggplot2   * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 knitr     * 1.40    2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 purrr     * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 readr     * 2.1.3   2022-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 shiny     * 1.7.2   2022-07-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 stringr   * 1.4.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 TBDBr     * 0.1.0   2022-09-03 [1] Github (Talkbank/TBDBr@f88caca)
 tibble    * 3.1.8   2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 tidyr     * 1.2.1   2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 tidyverse * 1.3.2   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)

 [1] /Users/francojc/R/Library
 [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library
```

Comment: That looks like `kableExtra` has changed the CSS for some components of the table that `kable()` uses.   I see the same change in R Markdown, this isn't Quarto-specific.  Piping the result into `kableExtra::kable_styling()` seems to fix it.

Comment: Another fix is to run `options(kableExtra.auto_format = FALSE)` before `kableExtra` gets loaded.  See https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/265 for a discussion.

Comment: And also if you are wondering why the caption is not working for the second table, you have a typo in the last chunk option `tab-cap`, it will be `tbl-cap` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user2554330, adding the `options(kableExtra.auto_format = FALSE)` before loading the `TBDBr` package worked great.

Also a big thanks for the typo catch @shafee. The table outputs are identical now as desired.